# How do you generate snippets for custom web parts to include on HTML master pages?

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage

In Sharepoint 2013, you can edit HTML master pages using the Design Manager and the Snippet Gallery.  How do you edit the list of web parts to include custom web parts so that it will generate the HTML snippet for you?  If that's not possible, is there any means of generating the snippet for an arbitrary web part?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your web part and upload it into the site's web part gallery. Then it will be available in the Snippet Gallery.